# DataTable.js doesn't load properly when using TABS

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I use DataTables.js to generate tables. It's great, works fine. I wanted to add Tabs to my "pages" but it seems that when DataTables is used on other than primary tab it doesn't load everything.

- First Tab
  [image]
- 2nd Tab
  [image]

Following is source code for one column/card that has DataTable added.

```
    <div class="three defaultColumn defaultCard">
                            <script>
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                    $("#DT-iuyx2s7b").DataTable({
                                        dom: "Bfrtip",
                                        buttons: [
                                            "copyHtml5",
                                            "excelHtml5",
                                            "csvHtml5",
                                            "pdfHtml5"
                                        ],
                                        colReorder: true,
                                        paging: true,
                                        pagingType: ["full_numbers"],
                                        lengthMenu: [
                                            [15, 25, 50, 100],
                                            -1,
                                            [15, 25, 50, 100],
                                            "All"
                                        ],
                                        ordering: true,
                                        info: true,
                                        procesing: true,
                                        responsive: {
                                            details: true
                                        },
                                        select: true,
                                        searching: true,
                                        stateSave: true
                                    });
                                });
                            </script>
                            <table id="DT-iuyx2s7b" class="display compact">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Id</th>
                                        <th>PriorityClass</th>
                                        <th>FileVersion</th>
                                        <th>HandleCount</th>
                                        <th>WorkingSet</th>
                                        <th>PagedMemorySize</th>
                                        <th>PrivateMemorySize</th>
                                        <th>VirtualMemorySize</th>
                                        <th>TotalProcessorTime</th>
                                        <th>SI</th>
                                        <th>Handles</th>
                                        <th>VM</th>
                                        <th>WS</th>
                                        <th>PM</th>
                                        <th>NPM</th>
                                        <th>Path</th>
                                        <th>Company</th>
                                        <th>CPU</th>
                                        <th>ProductVersion</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th>Product</th>
                                        <th>__NounName</th>
                                        <th>BasePriority</th>
                                        <th>ExitCode</th>
                                        <th>HasExited</th>
                                        <th>ExitTime</th>
                                        <th>Handle</th>
                                        <th>SafeHandle</th>
                                        <th>MachineName</th>
                                        <th>MainWindowHandle</th>
                                        <th>MainWindowTitle</th>
                                        <th>MainModule</th>
                                        <th>MaxWorkingSet</th>
                                        <th>MinWorkingSet</th>
                                        <th>Modules</th>
                                        <th>NonpagedSystemMemorySize</th>
                                        <th>NonpagedSystemMemorySize64</th>
                                        <th>PagedMemorySize64</th>
                                        <th>PagedSystemMemorySize</th>
                                        <th>PagedSystemMemorySize64</th>
                                        <th>PeakPagedMemorySize</th>
                                        <th>PeakPagedMemorySize64</th>
                                        <th>PeakWorkingSet</th>
                                        <th>PeakWorkingSet64</th>
                                        <th>PeakVirtualMemorySize</th>
                                        <th>PeakVirtualMemorySize64</th>
                                        <th>PriorityBoostEnabled</th>
                                        <th>PrivateMemorySize64</th>
                                        <th>PrivilegedProcessorTime</th>
                                        <th>ProcessName</th>
                                        <th>ProcessorAffinity</th>
                                        <th>Responding</th>
                                        <th>SessionId</th>
                                        <th>StartInfo</th>
                                        <th>StartTime</th>
                                        <th>SynchronizingObject</th>
                                        <th>Threads</th>
                                        <th>UserProcessorTime</th>
                                        <th>VirtualMemorySize64</th>
                                        <th>EnableRaisingEvents</th>
                                        <th>StandardInput</th>
                                        <th>StandardOutput</th>
                                        <th>StandardError</th>
                                        <th>WorkingSet64</th>
                                        <th>Site</th>
                                        <th>Container</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1Password</td>
                                        <td>16216</td>
                                        <td>Normal</td>
                                        <td>7.3.661</td>
                                        <td>901</td>
                                        <td>70991872</td>
                                        <td>157519872</td>
                                        <td>157519872</td>
                                        <td>747872256</td>
                                        <td>00:01:03.4531250</td>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>901</td>
                                        <td>747872256</td>
                                        <td>70991872</td>
                                        <td>157519872</td>
                                        <td>60464</td>
                                        <td>
                                            C:\Users\pklys\AppData\Local\1Password\app\7\1Password.exe
                                        </td>
                                        <td>AgileBits Inc.</td>
                                        <td>63,453125</td>
                                        <td>7.3.661</td>
                                        <td>1Password for Windows desktop</td>
                                        <td>1Password</td>
                                        <td>Process</td>
                                        <td>8</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>False</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>6076</td>
                                        <td>
                                            Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeProcessHandle
                                        </td>
                                        <td>.</td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>
                                            System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule
                                            (1Password.exe)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>1413120</td>
                                        <td>204800</td>
                                        <td>
                                            System.Diagnostics.ProcessModuleCollection
                                        </td>
                                        <td>60464</td>
                                        <td>60464</td>
                                        <td>157519872</td>
                                        <td>683568</td>
                                        <td>683568</td>
                                        <td>174804992</td>
                                        <td>174804992</td>
                                        <td>191524864</td>
                                        <td>191524864</td>
                                        <td>799748096</td>
                                        <td>799748096</td>
                                        <td>True</td>
                                        <td>157519872</td>
                                        <td>00:00:08.7343750</td>
                                        <td>1Password</td>
                                        <td>255</td>
                                        <td>True</td>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>
                                            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
                                        </td>
                                        <td>11.02.2019 19:10:11</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>
                                            System.Diagnostics.ProcessThreadCollection
                                        </td>
                                        <td>00:00:54.7187500</td>
                                        <td>747872256</td>
                                        <td>False</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>70991872</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

Full [source code](https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteHTML/blob/master/Examples/Example10/Example10.html) is on GitHub.

I've tried changing the code that is responsible for Tabs thinking it may be something wrong with the tabs I use but even after changing them behavior is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this is to initialize Datatables when the tab becomes active, and not at the page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href')) == "#Test1" && !$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable("#DT-iuyx2s7b") && !$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable("#DT-2u8iw0gr")) {
        $("#DT-iuyx2s7b").DataTable(...);
        $("#DT-2u8iw0gr").DataTable(...);
    } else if ($(this).attr('href')) == "#Test2" && !$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable("#DT-vdk1ir62")) {
        $("#DT-vdk1ir62").DataTable(...);
    }
  });
});
```

I don't take into consideration the first tab because it's the only visible one on page load.

JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dqec4xyw/

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with datatables, it is failing to render correctly when the table is within
a hidden container. You can verify it just by removing `display: none` style
from `.tab-pane`, all tabs shows up and all tables render correctly. But you have to hide
then tabs right?

Until datatables developers fixes this issue you have only one way to go. Keep all the
tab panes visible when page loads, let datatables render all the tables, then hide the
tab panes. So you have to tweak your tabs.

It seems datatables can render the tables even if container's visibility is set to hidden
if display is set to block. You can use this trick to hide the flash of all the tab panes
while the page is still loading. Just to give you an idea, add the following at the
bottom of your page withing the body tag.

```
<style id="datatables_crazyfix">
.tab-content .tab-pane {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
}
</style>
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#datatables_crazyfix").remove();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This seems to work...  is there anything that would prevent me from using this as is?

Comment: Yes, unless anything changes e.g class names. You can go with it as this is a temporary fix until datatables developers fixes it. Inform me if any other complexity pops up.

Comment: Great. I have one more problem with current tabs and so I will be porting this to a different solution for Tabs switching (as in different JS code). Hopefully, the same code will apply to a new solution.

Comment: Could you take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55148669/changing-tabs-behavior-impacting-datatables I changed how tabs are done and things aren't working anymore. I tried using yours but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

try:

change html code in tab:

```
  <div>
                <ul class="tab-nav">
                    <li><a class="button tabbtn active" href="#Test">Test </a></li>
                    <li><a class="button tabbtn" href="#Test1">Test1 </a></li>
                    <li><a class="button tabbtn" href="#Test2">Test2 </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

and

```
<script>
    $( ".tabbtn" ).on( "click", function() {
          setTimeout(function(){
             $("#DT-iuyx2s7b").DataTable({
                                                dom: "Bfrtip",
                                                destroy: true,
                                                buttons: [
                                                    "copyHtml5",
                                                    "excelHtml5",
                                                    "csvHtml5",
                                                    "pdfHtml5"
                                                ],
                                                colReorder: true,
                                                paging: true,
                                                pagingType: ["full_numbers"],
                                                lengthMenu: [
                                                    [15, 25, 50, 100],
                                                    -1,
                                                    [15, 25, 50, 100],
                                                    "All"
                                                ],
                                                ordering: true,
                                                info: true,
                                                procesing: true,
                                                responsive: {
                                                    details: true
                                                },
                                                select: true,
                                                searching: true,
                                                stateSave: true
                                            });
        },200)
        });
    </script>
```

or

```
             <script>
    var table=null;
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                table=    $("#DT-iuyx2s7b").DataTable({
                                        dom: "Bfrtip",
                                        buttons: [
                                            "copyHtml5",
                                            "excelHtml5",
                                            "csvHtml5",
                                            "pdfHtml5"
                                        ],
                                        colReorder: true,
                                        paging: true,
                                        pagingType: ["full_numbers"],
                                        lengthMenu: [
                                            [15, 25, 50, 100],
                                            -1,
                                            [15, 25, 50, 100],
                                            "All"
                                        ],
                                        ordering: true,
                                        info: true,
                                        procesing: true,
                                        responsive: {
                                            details: true
                                        },
                                        select: true,
                                        searching: true,
                                        stateSave: true
                                    });
                                });
    $( ".tabbtn" ).on( "click", function() {
          setTimeout(function(){
table.ajax.reload();
},300);
});
                            </script>
```

Comment: I am not sure what would be in your tab change button. I am a bit of noob when it comes to this.

Comment: I added a new answer

Comment: It works, sorta.. when pressing tab again I get DataTables warning: table id=DT-vdk1ir62 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: $("#DT-iuyx2s7b").dataTable().fnDestroy(); add code before $("#DT-iuyx2s7b").DataTable({....

Comment: if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#DT-vdk1ir62")) {
                            $("#DT-vdk1ir62")
                                .DataTable()
                                .clear()
                                .destroy();
                        }

Comment: But it doesn't help much.

Comment: i edited your code in question.  please try new code

Comment: Oh you edited my code, you shouldn't do that. YOu shoudld edit your answer instead.

Comment: sorry.  I just thought you could see

Comment: Generally, on StackOverflow, everything should go into 1 answer (from one person). Edits to the main question should only be done to clarify requesters question, not to provide an answer in it. Please edit your answer with code you believe fixes my issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, the last change doesn't help. No errors but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

Do a [responsive.recalc()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc()) on tabButton click. This will probably require the least amount of work.

```
tabButtons.map(function (button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document
      .querySelector("li a.active.button")
      .classList.remove("active");
    button.classList.add("active");

    document
      .querySelector(".tab-pane.active")
      .classList.remove("active");
    document
      .querySelector(button.getAttribute("href"))
      .classList.add("active");


    /****  ADDED RESPONSIVE.RECALC  ****/
    $(button.getAttribute("href"))
      .find("table.display.compact")
      .DataTable().responsive.recalc();
  })
})
```

#### Option 2

Initialize DataTable on tabButton click. In addition to the code shown below you will have to remove your other pieces of code that initializes the DataTable for the initially inactive tabs (Test1 and Test2).

I've found that this produces more consistent layout than Option 1.

```
tabButtons.map(function (button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document
      .querySelector("li a.active.button")
      .classList.remove("active");
    button.classList.add("active");

    document
      .querySelector(".tab-pane.active")
      .classList.remove("active");
    document
      .querySelector(button.getAttribute("href"))
      .classList.add("active");


    /**  ADDED DATATABLE INITIALIZATION HERE  **/
    var tabPaneToActivate = document
      .querySelector(button.getAttribute("href"))
    tabPaneToActivate.classList.add("active");
    tabPaneToActivate.querySelectorAll("table.display.compact").forEach(function (el) {
      if (!$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable(el)) {
        /** ^^^ Only initialize once ^^^ **/
        $(el).DataTable({
          dom: "Bfrtip",
          buttons: [
            "copyHtml5",
            "excelHtml5",
            "csvHtml5",
            "pdfHtml5"
          ],
          colReorder: true,
          paging: true,
          pagingType: ["full_numbers"],
          lengthMenu: [
            [15, 25, 50, 100],
            -1,
            [15, 25, 50, 100],
            "All"
          ],
          ordering: true,
          info: true,
          procesing: true,
          responsive: {
            details: true
          },
          select: true,
          searching: true,
          stateSave: true
        });

      }

    })
  })
})
```

Comment: I've added first and no real change (as in nothing happened). I added it at the bottom as JS script. Is there any special place I have to put that in?

Comment: @MadBoy Please see line 477 in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nireno/6py8fr71/2/) for the responsive recalc. Let me know if that is the result you expect.