# Changing tabs behavior impacting Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

This is a bit continuation of: [DataTable.js doesn't load properly when using TABS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638826/datatable-js-doesnt-load-properly-when-using-tabs)

Suggested code to my problem was like below. The idea is to load the table when Tab is clicked and it works great.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href')) == "#Test1" && !$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable("#DT-iuyx2s7b") && !$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable("#DT-2u8iw0gr")) {
        $("#DT-iuyx2s7b").DataTable(...);
        $("#DT-2u8iw0gr").DataTable(...);
    } else if ($(this).attr('href')) == "#Test2" && !$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable("#DT-vdk1ir62")) {
        $("#DT-vdk1ir62").DataTable(...);
    }
  });
});
```

I've since then changed how I work with tabs using solution from here: [Hiding, unhiding content on tab changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128507/hiding-unhiding-content-on-tab-changes)

```
<div class="wrapper">
<nav class="tabs">
    <div class="selector"></div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active" data-id="1"><i class="fas fa-burn"></i>Avengers</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="2"><i class="fas fa-bomb"></i>Guardians of The Galaxy</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="3"><i class="fas fa-bolt"></i>Thor</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="4"><i class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>Black Panther</a>
</nav>
</div>
```

So my href is `javascript:void(0)` and instead I'm using `data-id`.

Was:

```
<script>                    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).attr("href") == "#Tab-g4am0hvx" && !$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable("#DT-t37rnhwq")) {
                $('#DT-t37rnhwq').DataTable({
                    "dom": "Bfrtip",
                    "buttons": [
                        "copyHtml5",
                        "excelHtml5",
                        "csvHtml5",
                        "pdfHtml5"
                    ],
                    "colReorder": true,
                    "paging": true,
                    "pagingType": [
                        "full_numbers"
                    ],
                    "lengthMenu": [
                        [
                            15,
                            25,
                            50,
                            100
                        ],
                        -1,
                        [
                            15,
                            25,
                            50,
                            100
                        ],
                        "All"
                    ],
                    "ordering": true,
                    "info": true,
                    "procesing": true,
                    "responsive": {
                        "details": true
                    },
                    "select": true,
                    "searching": true,
                    "stateSave": true
                });
            };
        });
    });            
</script>
```

Is:

```
<script>                    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).attr("data-id") == "Tab-plsvqbkg" && !$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable("#DT-ni5ua9gr")) {
                $('#DT-ni5ua9gr').DataTable({
                    "dom": "Bfrtip",
                    "buttons": [
                        "copyHtml5",
                        "excelHtml5",
                        "csvHtml5",
                        "pdfHtml5"
                    ],
                    "colReorder": true,
                    "paging": true,
                    "pagingType": [
                        "full_numbers"
                    ],
                    "lengthMenu": [
                        [
                            15,
                            25,
                            50,
                            100
                        ],
                        -1,
                        [
                            15,
                            25,
                            50,
                            100
                        ],
                        "All"
                    ],
                    "ordering": true,
                    "info": true,
                    "procesing": true,
                    "responsive": {
                        "details": true
                    },
                    "select": true,
                    "searching": true,
                    "stateSave": true
                });
            };
        });
    });            
</script>
```

Each table is the same. First page looks like this:

[image]

The second page looks like this:

[image]

After I change it to my "new code"

[image]

So it seems to work partially. But it's missing the blue plus sign from the first page.

Full source for the page is here: https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteHTML/blob/master/Examples/Example10/Example10.html

Does anyone see where the problem is? maybe I'm missing something

EDIT.

I believe this is more related to table going out of bounds so the plus sign doesn't show up. It would seem my fix is actually working but for some reason on second tab table goes outside of visible area.

Comment: Change `$('a').on('click', function () { if ($(this).attr("href") == "#Tab-g4am0hvx"` to `$('.tabs').on('click', 'a', function (event) { if ($(event.target).attr("data-id") == "Tab-g4am0hvx"`.

Comment: Thank you! Works great! Can you make it an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @MunimMunna This seems to work, but it's acting weird from time to time. Like sometimes I open up and it doesn't load, i switch back and go in again and it shows up. Is there a reason it may be acting like that? Any way to force it to act properly?

Comment: I can see the NotWorking directory, but can't figure out what was the expected behavior here. Can you create an issue on GitHub with some details?

Comment: @MunimMunna that notworking is something else. You can take a look here. https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteHTML/blob/master/Examples/Example10-TableAndTabs/Example10.html It works, but it doesn't always work. Like 50/50. If i open it in google chrome and click right to 2nd tab it may not enable DataTables properly. If you switch and switch back it will enable. It's weird. It's very random.